# How to connect a USB dongle to Windows XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode, dongle

I'm trying to connect a [Matrix dongle](http://www.matrixlock.de/english/) to [Windows XP Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Windows_XP_Mode), but when looking under USB options it's not listed.

Example:

[image]

The dongle gets recognized by the Windows 7 device manager as a [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class)-compliant device, so it's properly connected.

How do I make Virtual PC recognize the dongle?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to other forums HID devices are unable to be assigned to Vitrual PC VMs.

Comment: I fear you are right...

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I would recommend using [VMware's player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). It is free and supports USB ports and add-on parallel ports. You most likely would need an available XP license though.

Comment: Apperently this same type of dongle gives us problems with VMWare as well :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox). It supports attaching USB devices to virtual machines.